# Nagios change Rule

Tags: curl, nagios

Hi I'm using nagios to monitor some services of my server.
I have one question.
Is there a way to execute a "curl" when there is a critical or warning message from nagios?.

I want to use it with check_http rule, but I dont know how to add the curl command.

so the curl withh trigger when a critical or warning message comes up

I'm using this command for check_http

```
command[check_http]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http -H "foo.com" -f follow -s "bar" -w 5 -c 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a handler command for this and call the curl command from the handler script. You can write the handler in any language that you like.